# Adding several named route middlewares with NuxtJS not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware, nuxtjs3

I've been trying to set two different named route middlewares but for some reason the second one doesn't work whereas the first one does.

Here is my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    plugins: [
        '~/plugins/fontawesome.ts',
        '~/plugins/firebase.client.ts',
        '~/plugins/guard-secret.ts'
    ],
    // ...
})
```

My plugin `guard-secret.ts`:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    addRouteMiddleware('guard-secret', () => {
        // auth is provided elsewhere via another plugin: `firebase.client.ts`
        const { $auth } = useNuxtApp();
        if(!$auth?.currentUser?.uid) { // todo.
            return navigateTo('/');
        }
    });

    addRouteMiddleware('guard-already-logged-in', () => {
        const { $auth } = useNuxtApp();
        if ($auth) {
            if ($auth.currentUser.email === "xxx") {
                return navigateTo('/admin/');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then, `admin/index.vue` (which works as expected):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  middleware: ["guard-secret"],
});
</script>

<template>
 <div></div>
</template>
```

Now `admin/login.value` (which raises an error):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  middleware: ["guard-already-logged-in"],
});
</script>

<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
```

The middleware `guard-already-logged-in` doesn't work for unknown reasons, it says (on the page):

```
500
Unknown route middleware: 'guard-already-logged-in'. Valid middleware: .
```

I've tried to restart the app, to rename the file, to rename the routes, but nothing changed.